# How to change webpack path to an upper directory(root) in Laravel?

Tags: laravel, webpack, laravel-mix

Due to security reasons I move all directories and files into a main directory and took out all files/directories from public folder to root of Laravel project. Now I want to `npm run dev` in order to compile scss files to css and js to js. However each time I run `npm run dev` it creates a folder named `public` inside the main folder I had created and put compiled files into that.  But I want to put it in root folder which contains: css-js-svg-fonts-index so I changed

This:

```
mix.js('resources/js/app.js', 'public/js')
    .sass('resources/sass/app.scss', 'public/css');
```

to this:

```
mix.js('resources/js/app.js', '../../js')
    .sass('resources/sass/app.scss', '../../css');
```

but no result :( it just creates public folder inside main folder that is not the root I want it to be one level upper.

Thanks

Answer (score 6):

I found it :)

```
mix.setPublicPath('../')
    .js('resources/js/app.js', 'js')
    .sass('resources/sass/app.scss', 'css');
```

but previously I was wrong with an extra slash which was:

```
mix.setPublicPath('../')
    .js('resources/js/app.js', '/js')
    .sass('resources/sass/app.scss', '/css');
```